# Check if registry has been deleted with python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

How can I check if database data is missing?

```
 if cur.execute('DELETE FROM products WHERE shop = 5'):
       print('deleted sucess')
```

This code doesn't work and I didn't find how I can validate if the data has been deleted

Comment: Check if the data exists before you delete it. If it exists, delete it. If you want to make sure it was deleted, then query the same data and ensure you get nothing back. Although any decent database wouldn't require you to verify that a deletion indeed occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure the motivation behind this extra check, but you can verify the [`cur.rowcount`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount) value, which returns the number of "affected rows" in your last query:

> This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that the last `.execute*()` produced (for DQL statements like `SELECT`) or affected (for `DML` statements like `UPDATE` or `INSERT`). [9]

```
cur.execute('DELETE FROM products WHERE shop = 5')

affected_rows = cur.rowcount
print("Rows affected: {affected_rows}".format(affected_rows=affected_rows))

if affected_rows > 0: 
    print('deleted success')
```

Comment: The purpose is to check if certain data has been deleted to make a new insert.
Or you must delete all data from each store before entering new ones.

Comment: @JB_ gotcha, thanks for the additional info. Have you considered using database level constraints to prevent inserts?

Comment: I don't know how I know how I could use it for sure @alecxe

Answer (score 1):

You can delete then attempt to select what was deleted.  This code should tell you if the delete was successful, though it's not very efficient... the database should delete the data and if it doesn't then you should pick a new database.

```
cur.execute('DELETE FROM products WHERE shop = 5')
cur.execute('SELECT * from products where shop = 5')
if not cur.fetchone():
    print('delete successful')
```